# My partials doesn't working

Tags: ruby, windows, sinatra, haml

I am trying to split my HAML view to the separate files.  I have read the [Sinatra Book](http://sinatra-book.gittr.com/#implementation_of_rails_style_partials) and tried to implement the basic version.

So I have created **app_helpers.rb** file:

```
# Usage: partial :foo
helpers do
  def partial(page, options={})
    haml page, options.merge!(:layout => false)
  end
end
```

And require it in my **application.rb**:

```
require 'sinatra'
require_relative './app_helpers.rb'
```

Then I have created partial views/test.haml:

```
<h3> Test message </h3>
```

And require it in my **index.haml**:

```
= partial :test
```

But when I refresh my page I get the error message:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `partial' for #<Application:0x514dbe0>:
        c:/Dropbox/development/myprojects/test/sinatra-bootstrap/views/index.haml:27:in `evaluate_source'
        C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/tilt-1.3.3/lib/tilt/template.rb:209:in `instance_eval'
        C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/tilt-1.3.3/lib/tilt/template.rb:209:in `evaluate_source'
        C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/tilt-1.3.3/lib/tilt/template.rb:144:in `cached_evaluate'
        C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/tilt-1.3.3/lib/tilt/template.rb:127:in `evaluate'
        C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/tilt-1.3.3/lib/tilt/haml.rb:24:in `evaluate'
        C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/tilt-1.3.3/lib/tilt/template.rb:76:in `render'
        C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb:625:in `render'
        C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb:522:in `haml'
```

How can I fix it?

**Updated:**

All works fine if I rewrite **app_helpers.rb** such way:

```
def partial(page, options={})
    haml page, options.merge!(:layout => false)
end
```

What is the reason of this?

Comment: sinatra doesn't find the helper method. have you rebooted the application?

Comment: What happens when you don't split it off into a separate file and put the `helpers` block directly in your `application.rb` file?

Comment: I have rebooted application. And I have put app_helpers.rb to application.rb.  The problem remains the same.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Pls comment if you have any ideas of this behavior.

Comment: what does the helper method do and where does it get initiated?

Comment: Can't reproduce. I guess it's something mundane...

Comment: @ericraio I don't know. I get this code in Sinatra book: http://sinatra-book.gittr.com/#implementation_of_rails_style_partials

Comment: I can't reproduce it too. I guess it's platform specific issue, maybe something wrong with `Sinatra::Delegator`. You can try [using `Sinatra::Base`](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Sinatra::Base%20-%20Middleware,%20Libraries,%20and%20Modular%20Apps) instead of classic style.

Comment: This method is not necessary. You can just call `haml :test`. Sinatra (since 1.2.0) will automatically detect that this call is coming from another template and set the `:layout` option to `nil`.

Comment: on a related note, <h3></h3> is not haml.

Comment: @three Well, it's not the _joy_ of Haml, but Haml does let you enter into raw HTML output if you desire.

Comment: @KonstantinHaase Actually, it looks like your work on that has been there [since 1.1](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/CHANGES#L443).

Comment: @Phrogz right, sorry, sometimes I mix up changelog entries in my memory. Anyhow, it's part of all still supported versions.

Answer (score 1):

Sinatra partials had a good section in the [FAQs](http://www.sinatrarb.com/faq.html#partials). There use to be [gist](https://gist.github.com/119874) which contained a file you needed to create. However they have now created a gem [Sinatra-Partial](https://github.com/yb66/Sinatra-Partial).

My recommendation would be to use this gem for partials ([Sinatra-Partial](https://github.com/yb66/Sinatra-Partial)).

Answer (score 0):

Cannot reproduce:

```
C:\test>cat views\layout.haml
%body= yield

C:\test>cat views\index.haml
#main=partial :test

C:\test>cat views\test.haml
%h3 Hello World

C:\test>cat test_partial.rb
require 'sinatra'
require 'haml'

helpers do
  def partial(page, options={})
    haml page, options.merge!(:layout => false)
  end
end

get '/' do
  haml :index
end

c:\test>ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18) [i386-mingw32]

C:\test>curl http://127.0.0.1:4567/
<body><div id='main'><h3>Hello World</h3></div></body>
```

However, as noted by @Konstantin, using a custom `partials` method is no longer necessary as of Sinatra 1.1.0. If I change `index.haml` to just `#main=haml :test` and delete the `partials` method, the output is the same.

*In earlier versions of Sinatra you would have seen the output:*

```html
<body><div id='main'><body><h3>Hello World</h3></body></div></body>
```